# Train rasa_core to predict the next intent according to stories.md

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Need help for this one. I want to know how can I train my bot to predict the next intent according to what I have in stories.md.

To be clear: I have an intent ‘problem’ in this intent I don’t know what the user could tape. It can be every thing that the user qualify that it’s a problem for him. All what I know is that this intent will occur in a certain phase of the conversation . for example:

```
## story1
* greet
    - utter_greet
* confirm
    - utter_step1
* probleme
    - action_SendIntentProbleme
    - utter_probleme_site
```

So here I know that always after utter_step1 the user will give me his problem, and I don’t need to understand it I just need the bot to qualify it as intent problem to be able after this to execute action_sendintentproblem and then utter_problem_site. The bot answer for this intent is general. no matter what is the content of this intent.

I want my bot when listening to the user after Utter_step1 to know that the next input will be intent ‘probleme’, can I specify this in my data.md file? or do I need to add this in the configuration file and how?

Thank you for your help

Comment: My first Idea to counter this is to tell the user to begin his sentance with : "the problem is: " and then in my data.md I declare an intent problem that contain : "the problem is:"  But not sure if this will work always and then If I have a lot of these kind of intents I'll be asking the user each time to begin the sentance with something which is not good

Comment: what kind of problems come under probleme intent?  Are they specific health related issues that you are trying to capture?

Comment: In fact it's about problems in management. It's in french but I'll try to give examples. One person can say: I can't find a way to make my project work.  Another user will say: We don't communicate in our group.   Another user will say: I have hard time with my employees, etc.   And These are just examples that I came with, I don't know nothing about what a user could judge as problem for him

Comment: One way is to treat it a default_fallback and then in the fallback action you could capture it and utter what you need and then fall back to the previous state.

Comment: Thank you Srikar, can you please give an example on how to do this, or a documentation. I know what the default_fallback action is but I don't know how to use it as I want to. I'am new to this

Comment: Refer the code in the docs: https://rasa.com/docs/core/_modules/rasa_core/actions/action/#ActionDefaultFallback

In the run block, execute your functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [forms](https://rasa.com/docs/core/slotfilling/) for this use case.

The story should look like:

```
## story1
* greet
    - utter_greet
* confirm
    - utter_step1
    - problem_form
    - form{"name": "problem_form"}
    - form{"name": null}
    - action_SendIntentProbleme
    - utter_probleme_site
```

In your domain file add:

```
intents:
  ...

slots:
  problem_message
    type: unfeaturized
  ...

forms:
  - problem_form

actions:
  - utter_ask_problem_message

templates:
  utter_ask_problem_message:
    text: "What is your problem?"
```

In your core policy configuration add the forms policy:

```
policies:
  - name: FormPolicy
  ...
```

And then have a form like:

```
from rasa_core_sdk.forms import FormAction

class ProblemForm(FormAction):
    """Accept free text input from the user for suggestions"""

    def name(self):
        return "problem_form"

    @staticmethod
    def required_slots(tracker):
        return ["problem_message"]

    def slot_mappings(self):
        return {"problem_message": self.from_text()}

    def submit(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        return []
```

This form will call `utter_ask_problem_message` until the slot is filled by the user. As we call `self.from_text()` the slot will be filled with the whole message.

Comment: Yes I see, but the problem in my intent problem is that the user can realy say anything that come in mind. I can give 30 examples of intent problem and the one the user give will be very different.  For my counter idea I know it has nothing to loses the fact that I'am using an intellegent bot. But I didn't find another way to do it.

Comment: Yes I see, but the problem in my intent problem is that the user can realy say anything that come in mind. I can give 30 examples of intent problem and the one the user give will be very different. For my counter idea I know it loses the fact that I'am using an intellegent bot. But I didn't find another way to do it.

Comment: @chemssou I now had a similar problem to yours, and solved it using forms. I edited my answer with the suggested solution.

Comment: You're welcome :-) please accept the answer as correct if this did help you so that other users can find it.

Comment: I actualy can't because I have less than 15 reputation. Each time I want to do it It tells me that the vote is accepted but will not be shown as I don't have enogh reputation to vote

Comment: No worries :-) Main point is that I could help you after nearly a month :-D

Comment: Yes sir, Thank you again. Can I connect with you ? via linkedin for example